# Error updating CocoaPods after upgrading to flutter 3.0.1

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, cocoapods, podfile

I am using **MacBook Pro, M1 Chip**. OS is **MacOS Monterey 12.3.1**

today I upgraded flutter from 2.5.4 to 3.0.1.

I can run my projects perfectly fine in Android. However in iOS I get the following error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods recommended version 1.11.0 or greater not installed.
Pods handling may fail on some projects involving plugins.
To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Finding Podfile changes
      A google_sign_in_ios
      A image_picker_ios
      A url_launcher_ios
      R amazon_s3_cognito
      R google_sign_in
      R image_picker
      R url_launcher
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - file_picker
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_messaging
      - firebase_storage
      - flutter_image_compress
      - flutter_keyboard_visibility
      - flutter_pdfview
      - geolocator_apple
      - google_maps_flutter
      - image_cropper
      - maps_launcher
      - open_file
      - path_provider_ios
      - shared_preferences_ios
      - sqflite
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `file_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/file_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
    firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_image_compress` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_image_compress/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_keyboard_visibility` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_keyboard_visibility/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_pdfview` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_pdfview/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `geolocator_apple` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_maps_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_cropper` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `maps_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/maps_launcher/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `open_file` from `.symlinks/plugins/open_file/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_1_6_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/6/1/DKImagePickerController/4.3.2/DKImagePickerController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_a_d_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/5.1.0/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.1.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_7_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.6.1/TOCropViewController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_5_d_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/5/d/c/Mantle/2.2.0/Mantle.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_1_1_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/1/1/7/SDWebImage/5.12.2/SDWebImage.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_9_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/9/d/SDWebImageWebPCoder/0.8.4/SDWebImageWebPCoder.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_4_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn":
      In Podfile:
        google_sign_in_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
          GoogleSignIn (~> 6.2)
    None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `GoogleSignIn (~> 6.2)`.
    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * mistyped the name or version.
     * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Ignoring ffi-1.15.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.3
Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
Exited
```

I tried `pod install` inside the ios folder. Below is the output.

```
Ignoring ffi-1.15.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.3
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn":
  In Podfile:
    google_sign_in_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 6.2)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `GoogleSignIn (~> 6.2)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I tried `pod update` and below is the output.

````
Ignoring ffi-1.15.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.3
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod update
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 12.3.1 (21E258)
       Xcode : 13.4 (13F17a)
         Git : git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:78:in `deprecated_local_podspecs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:60:in `preheat_existing_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:257:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:135:in `block (3 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `block in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:145:in `block in update_repositories'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:143:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:143:in `update_repositories'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/update.rb:63:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.3%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+tried%3A+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.3%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64e%27%29%29+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.3%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
````

This is what `flutter doctor` has to say

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale
    en-LK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4)
    ! CocoaPods 1.10.1 out of date (1.11.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Months back when installing the flutter in this M1 chip, i can remember I had to safe similar issues with `ffi`. If my memory is right, i had to install it separately with another command.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is what I had to do..

First, update the FFI

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Navigate to the project's ios folder...

Now update the pods for M1 Chip

```
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Now install pods for M1 Chip

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: Same error even on running in x86 arch

Answer (score 10):

Just follow the below intructions;

Go main project folder and run the below lines

```
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
sudo arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: I will check. I thought the issue is FFI and M1 Chip related?

Comment: `cache clean --all` doesnt work. It says `Permission denied : cache`. I used `sudo`, then it says `sudo: cache: command not found`

Comment: You should add 'pod' prefix, I changed the answer detail. @PeakGen

Comment: I also recommend deleting the `ios/Pods` folder after deleting the `Podfile.lock`