# Updating Pods with `pod repo update` fails with an error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos, cocoapods

I have **Macbook pro M1 Chip**. I am developing a flutter app. After updating to flutter 3.0.1 I am trying to update the pods, so I have passed the command `pod repo update`.

However I ended up with the below error

```
        Updating spec repo `trunk`
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x0000000104e0c000
        ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
        
        -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
           See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
             * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
             * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
           for more details.                                                        
        Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     
        
        -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
        c:0034 p:---- s:0214 e:000213 CFUNC  :attach
        c:0033 p:0258 s:0208 e:000207 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:275
        c:0032 p:0050 s:0188 e:000187 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:17
        c:0031 p:0007 s:0185 e:000184 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:7
        c:0030 p:0007 s:0182 e:000181 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:2 [FINISH]
        c:0029 p:---- s:0179 e:000178 CFUNC  :require
        c:0028 p:0110 s:0174 e:000173 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
        c:0027 p:0042 s:0162 e:000161 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:15 [FINISH]
        c:0026 p:---- s:0159 e:000158 CFUNC  :require
        c:0025 p:0110 s:0154 e:000153 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
        c:0024 p:0013 s:0142 e:000141 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2 [FINISH]
        c:0023 p:---- s:0139 e:000138 CFUNC  :require
        c:0022 p:0110 s:0134 e:000133 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
        c:0021 p:0006 s:0122 e:000121 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440
        c:0020 p:0045 s:0114 e:000113 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372
        c:0019 p:0318 s:0103 e:000102 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365
        c:0018 p:0006 s:0093 e:000092 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338
        c:0017 p:0006 s:0088 e:000087 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:78
        c:0016 p:0008 s:0084 e:000082 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:60
        c:0015 p:0009 s:0078 e:000077 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:257
        c:0014 p:0009 s:0073 e:000072 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:135
        c:0013 p:0081 s:0069 e:000068 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64
        c:0012 p:0033 s:0062 e:000061 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:134 [FINISH]
        c:0011 p:---- s:0058 e:000057 CFUNC  :each
        c:0010 p:0022 s:0054 e:000053 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133 [FINISH]
        c:0009 p:---- s:0050 e:000049 CFUNC  :open
        c:0008 p:0082 s:0044 e:000043 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131
        c:0007 p:0027 s:0036 e:000035 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23
        c:0006 p:0078 s:0031 e:000030 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334
        c:0005 p:0024 s:0024 e:000023 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52
        c:0004 p:0378 s:0019 e:000018 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55 [FINISH]
        c:0003 p:---- s:0013 e:000012 CFUNC  :load
        c:0002 p:0109 s:0008 E:001680 EVAL   /usr/local/bin/pod:23 [FINISH]
        c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:000150 (none) [FINISH]
        
        -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
        /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
        /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23:in `run'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `update'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `open'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `block in update'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `each'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in update'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:135:in `block (3 levels) in update'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:257:in `update'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:60:in `preheat_existing_files'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:78:in `deprecated_local_podspecs'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:7:in `<module:Ethon>'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:17:in `<module:Libc>'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:275:in `attach_function'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:275:in `attach'
        
        -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
        
        * Loaded script: /usr/local/bin/pod
        
        * Loaded features:
        
            0 enumerator.so
            1 thread.rb
            2 rational.so
            3 complex.so
            4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/enc/encdb.bundle
            5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
            6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/rbconfig.rb
            7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
            8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
            9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
           10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/errors.rb
           11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb
           12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
           13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/platform.rb
    // I HAD TO TAKE DOWN MORE SIMILAR ERRORS TO LIMIT THE LENGTH OF THIS ERROR
          117 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/pathname.bundle
          118 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb
          119 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/ansi/cursor.rb
          120 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/ansi/graphics.rb
          121 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/ansi/string_escaper.rb
          122 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/ansi.rb
          123 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/argument.rb
          124 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/argv.rb
          125 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/banner.rb
          126 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb
          127 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command/argument_suggester.rb
          128 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb
          129 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/informative_error.rb
          130 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/help.rb
          131 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide.rb
          132 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2/codes.rb
          133 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable/impl.rb
          134 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb
          135 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2/ascii_decorator.rb
          136 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2/strings.rb
          137 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2.rb
          138 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.20.0/lib/xcodeproj/gem_version.rb
          139 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.20.0/lib/xcodeproj/user_interface.rb
          140 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.20.0/lib/xcodeproj.rb
          141 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/strip.rb
          142 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/constants.rb
          143 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/engine.rb
          144 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/abstract_object.rb
          145 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb
          146 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mri_object.rb
          147 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/jruby_object.rb
          148 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/rbx_object.rb
          149 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/truffleruby_object.rb
          150 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/object.rb
          151 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/volatile.rb
          152 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/abstract_lockable_object.rb
          153 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb
          154 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/jruby_lockable_object.rb
          155 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/rbx_lockable_object.rb
          156 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/lockable_object.rb
          157 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/condition.rb
          158 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/lock.rb
          159 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb
          160 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/map/non_concurrent_map_backend.rb
          161 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/map/mri_map_backend.rb
          162 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb
          163 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append.rb
          164 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/regexp.rb
          165 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb
          166 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb
          167 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb
          168 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/thread_safe/util.rb
          169 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/hash.rb
          170 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n/version.rb
          171 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/cgi/core.rb
          172 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/cgi/escape.bundle
          173 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/cgi/util.rb
          174 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/cgi/cookie.rb
          175 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/cgi.rb
          176 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb
          177 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb
          178 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n.rb
          179 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb
          180 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n/config.rb
          181 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-
          207 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb
          208 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/date_core.bundle
          209 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/date.rb
          210 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb
          211 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/base64.rb
          212 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/bigdecimal.bundle
          213 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bigdecimal.rb
          214 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb
          215 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb
          216 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb
          217 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-
    // I HAD TO TAKE DOWN MANY SIMILAR ERRORS TO LIMIT THE LENGTH OF THIS ERROR
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/digest.bundle
          259 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/digest.rb
          260 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/request.rb
          261 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/response.rb
          262 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb
          263 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector/version.rb
          264 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb
          265 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/strscan.bundle
          266 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb
          267 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/socket.bundle
          268 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/io/wait.bundle
          269 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/socket.rb
          270 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb
    //I HAD TO REMOVE FEW SIMILAR ERRORS TO LIMIT THE LENGTH OF THIS ERROR
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb
          383 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/logging.rb
          384 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-
          465 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb
          466 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/trunk_source.rb
          467 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb
          468 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb
          469 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods.rb
          470 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb
          471 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/errors.rb
          472 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/options/repo_update.rb
          473 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/options/project_directory.rb
          474 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/cache/list.rb
          475 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-
          546 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/digest/sha2.bundle
          547 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/digest/sha2.rb
          548 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
          549 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/platform.rb
          550 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/data_converter.rb
          551 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/types.rb
          552 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/library.rb
          553 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/errno.rb
          554 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/abstract_memory.rb
          555 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/pointer.rb
          556 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/memorypointer.rb
          557 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/struct_layout.rb
          558 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/struct_layout_builder.rb
          559 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/struct_by_reference.rb
          560 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/struct.rb
          561 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/union.rb
          562 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/managedstruct.rb
          563 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/callback.rb
          564 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/io.rb
          565 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/autopointer.rb
          566 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/variadic.rb
          567 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/enum.rb
          568 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/version.rb
          569 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/ffi.rb
          570 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi.rb
        
        [NOTE]
        You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
        Bug reports are welcome.
        For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
        
        [IMPORTANT]
        Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
        DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.
        
        zsh: abort      pod repo update
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: do you have m1 chip?

Comment: @SimonSot: Of course! MacBook Pro M1 Chip

Comment: had same last week, try these commands https://stackoverflow.com/a/72359238/13701546

Comment: @SimonSot: Okay, let me try.

Comment: @SimonSot: `cache clean --all` doesnt work. It says `Permission denied : cache`. I used `sudo`, then it says `sudo: cache: command not found`

Comment: ok have a look here. hope smth from it will help https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10287

Comment: @SimonSot: Yes, through your link I managed to build an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I had to do is,

First navigate to the project's `ios` folder and update the pods for M1 Chip

```
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Now install pods

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```